# Mongo - Ignore property from being persisted

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-document

I have a standard POJO that has a set of properties in it. The POJO has been annotated as a `@Document`, so as to be persisted in MongoDB as a Document.

How (annotation??) can I ignore/avoid one of the properties in the POJO from being persisted?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The [`@Transient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/Transient.html) annotation it is. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-annotations

Comment: for anyone who is working with native mongo code, try `@BsonIgnore` annotation.

Answer (score 53):

In case you are looking for the actual package like I was, this one will work:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
```

Which is from the [Spring framework API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/Transient.html) documentation.

But this one, which is a [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) annotation, will not work for MongoDB:

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;
```

Which is part of the [Java Persistence API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html).

Answer (score 3):

use `@Transient`
be aware that you use the below package

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
```

Comment: if we don't use spring?