# Mongo, js - Ignore property from being persisted

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How to prevent a property in mongo form being persisted in javascript?

I found a solution for this in Java world: [Mongo - Ignore property from being persisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254856/mongo-ignore-property-from-being-persisted) Basically, you just annotate a field with `@Transient` annotation.

Let's say I have an object and I dont want to store property `transient`:

```
{
  keepA: 1,
  keepB: 2,
  transinet: "don't persist me"
}
```

So after loading from mongoDb I would get this object:

```
{
  keepA: 1,
  keepB: 2
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a feeling. That in Java, Spring takes care of the creation of an object that will be persisted. So the framework strips out the annotated transient field. **So mongoDb itself doesn't have any handles for transient fields.**

If I am wrong please correct me.

**Workaround**

One could use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and its [omit](https://lodash.com/docs#omit) function. To strip unwanted fields.