# MongoDB avoid persisting some fields in POJO - Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I’m trying to avoid persisting some fields in my POJO in to MongoDB.

I tried

1) Adding  `@javax.persistence.Transient` on field.

2)  Adding `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` on field
even i do not use spring at all.

3) Make the field `transient`

I am using Jakson as the default ObjectMapper of mongodb. and i am not using Spring data to interact with database

But no luck.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254856/mongo-ignore-property-from-being-persisted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo - Ignore property from being persisted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254856/mongo-ignore-property-from-being-persisted)

Comment: I have tried that spring @Transient , but it won't work. can't you see that i have mentioned it on my question????

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `javax.persistence.Transient` But this one, which is a JPA annotation, will not work for MongoDB:

If you want you can use Spring framework @Transient annotation.
[Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-annotations)

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
```

I tried with Spring framework which is working fine for me.

> Sample example

```
@Transient
    private Integer age;
```

If above solution not working the there might be an issue with `MappingMongoConverter`
Annotation based mapping only works if you're using the MappingMongoConverter ([Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb:mapping-configuration)) as backing converter for `MongoTemplate`. If you're not configuring the converter a `SimpleMongoConverter` will be used by default that simply serializes objects into Mongo without taking a look at any meta information whatsoever.